# Unable to send data to druid using docker-druid image

Tags: apache-zookeeper, druid

I am trying to use the docker-druid image to run a druid cluster.

I started the cluster as per the instructions in the github wiki.

```
docker run --rm -i -p 3000:8082 -p 3001:8081 druidio/example-cluster
```

I can access the druid cluster console at *192.168.99.100:8081* as well as coordinator console at *192.168.99.100:8090* successfully.

However i am unable to send any data to druid instance on this cluster using `tranquility`.

I am using the [Tranquility Java Example](https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/metamx/tranquility/example/JavaExample.java) to send data to druid. In this case tranquility is used as a library and not as a server. This example program works fine and is able to send data to druid if i setup druid locally on a VM as per the instructions in [Getting started guide](http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/index.html)

however if i try to use the dockerized druid, no data is sent to it. Neither do i see any errors. I am configuring the address of the default docker machine in my tranquility configuration as shown below:

```
 "properties" : {
  "zookeeper.connect" : "192.168.99.100",
  "druid.discovery.curator.path" : "/druid/discovery",
  "druid.selectors.indexing.serviceName" : "druid/overlord",
  "http.port" : "8200",
  }
```

Is there any additional configuration required when using docker-druid in order to send data to it from a Java application using tranquility?

Does tranquility locate druid services using zookeeper which would require zookeeper ports to be opened?

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing port 8200 in your docker config if you add `-p 8200:8200` you should be good to go. For more information check out https://github.com/implydata/distribution-docker